# TypedReferences and __makeref keyword with C# and UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a UWP app and i have a method which uses a TypedReference and __makeref  keyword, now when i run with debug mode it runs without any problem , but when i try to take a release or run in release mode it makes an internal server error, i think its from the native compiler which makes the error, i have searched very much and tried to replace the TypedReference  with something else but i couldn't,

Image of the method which contains TypedReference in my app:

[image]

Tip : when i comment the lines which contains __makeref  keyword it runs OK in release mode also,

and the error is :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.7-rel-27913-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.7-rel-27913-00\tools\x64\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe @"D:\MasulkaRole\Masulka\Desktop\Masulka\obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\Masulka.rsp"' returned exit code -214748364